# check processor architecture and proceed with if statement

Tags: powershell, architecture, processor

i know that here are a lot of examples how to get the processor architecture.

this should get the type with true or false checking on x64

my question is: how do i get this output into a if statement?

example: if it is an 64bit processor THEN perform a few steps and if it is 32bit then perform other steps. how can i go on further?

i tried a few versions of code but also got true or false back which is ok but how to go on further?

can you help me out guys?

thanks

Comment: Please show some examples of what You already tried. I guess You got problems with if statement itselft not with getting the architecture. Also, try to rewrite Your question once again as it is not clear what You actually want.

Comment: https://sqlpowershell.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/powershell-find-os-architecture-32-bit-or-64-bit-of-local-or-remote-machines-using-powershell/

Answer (score 2):

thank you all.

i solved it by using the following:

```
$os_type = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).SystemType -match ‘(x64)’

if ($os_type -eq "True") {
    Write-Host "i am an 64bit OS"
    write-host $os_type }
else {
    $os_type = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).SystemType -match ‘(x86)’

    if ($os_type -eq "True") {
        Write-Host "i am a 32 Bit OS" }
```

Answer (score 1):

`[System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess` returns true or false, so it's a very simple `if` statement.

```
if ([System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess) {
# Do 64-bit stuff
} else {
#Do 32-bit stuff
}
```

You didn't specify which of the "lot of examples" you're using, so I showed the method I use.

Comment: Note that this tells if the *process* is 64 bit, not necessarily the operating system. If you run the x86 PowerShell on a x64 machine, that will give different results. Depending on what the OP wants to do, that may be fine or even desired. But it's worth noting nonetheless.

Comment: thanks for your reply! i do not want to get info about a process. i need to know if it is an 64bit OS or an 32bit OS by checking the processor architecture - or is there a easier solution to get this info and go on further with it in an if statement?

Comment: Perhaps then `[Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem`

Answer (score 1):

Could also use the environment variables.

```
$Is64bitProcess = $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -eq 'AMD64'
$Is64bitOs = $Is64bit = $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 -eq 'AMD64'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alroc's answer works for powershell 3.0 or above i believe. In case there is an issue with that another approach would be this:

```
$architecture = (Get-WmiObject win32_processor | Where-Object{$_.deviceID -eq "CPU0"}).AddressWidth
If ($architecture -eq 64) {
    # Do 64-bit stuff
} else {
    #Do 32-bit stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply: when i'm trying your code it give me following error:

Get-WmiObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: This code was copied from an install script so i forgot to remove my $computer variable. updated.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your input!

i tried for example this:

Thank you for your answer! i tried for example the following:

```
    echo "check if 32 or 64bit OS"
    $var = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).SystemType -match ‘(x64)’
    if ($var = "True") {echo "i am an 64bit OS"

    #setting the current directory as the directory the script is in
    $sourcenssm= Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

    #setting the targetdirectory for nssm
    $targetnssm="C:\Users\cp\Desktop\nssm.exe"

    #setting the current directory as the directory the script is in
    $sourcewts= Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

    #setting the targetdirectory for wtswatchdog
    $targetwts="C:\Windows\wtswatchdog.exe"

    #copying nssm to target - WORKING
    if (-not(Test-path $targetnssm)) {Copy-item -Path $sourcenssm\nssm.exe -Destination $targetnssm}

    #copying wtswatchdog to target - CHECK!
    if (-not(Test-path $targetwts)) {Copy-item -Path $sourcewts\wtswatchdog.exe -Destination $targetwts}
}
```

but it gives me everytime 64 bit as an output also if i am checking

```
 echo "check if 32 or 64bit OS"
            $var = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).SystemType -match ‘(x86)’
            if ($var = "True") {echo "i am an 64bit OS"}
```

then it is also going to the echo-part.